# How to add multiple accounts

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts

I was trying to create an account via geth. My question is about using the non-interactive password input.

With the following variables :

```
GETH_ROOT_PATH="${HOME}/Chain_Test"
GETH_DATA_DIR="${GETH_ROOT_PATH}/chaindata"
BR2="}"
PASSWORD="${GETH_ROOT_PATH}/passwordfile.txt" => in this file, I have something like : 

l1: {ADDR1}password1

l2: {ADDR2}password2 

.....
```

So I have tried this :

```
geth account new --datadir ${GETH_DATA_DIR} --password awk -F"$BR2" '[ print $2 ]' ${PASSWORD}
```

So what I wanted is to go to the password file and take the output following the "}" and to make it as the password of the account.

But it didn't work.
Could you help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're password file syntax is incorrect, and is limited to one password per file followed by a single newline, not multiple passwords per file.

Are you on linux? If so I would hazard a guess that you're shell expansion is causing an issue as well, and whatever it is you're trying to accomplish is very unnecessary.

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts#non-interactive-use

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes I am on a CentOS 7. I have tried this : geth account new --password <(echo $mypassword) and it worked with the previous definition of the variable mypassword, for a single account. What I'm trying now, is to create a loop for creating 7 accounts at the same time for example. I will continue my researchs. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind marking my post as the answer that would be great :)